# How to properly use css-values viewport-relative-lengths?

Tags: css, responsive-design, font-size

As per [Is there a way to up-size the font with CSS to fit the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972851/is-there-a-way-to-up-size-the-font-with-css-to-fit-the-screen), it's possible to use [css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) ([dev3](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values-3/#viewport-relative-lengths), [dev](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)), `vw`, `vh`, `vmin`, `vmax`, to make the document more fluid.

However, coming from the conservative side, I'd like to ensure that my desire to fit the screen on larger displays doesn't do harm on smaller ones.

I know that with `<meta name = 'viewport' content = 'width = device-width' />` and the implicit `font-size: 1em;`, I'm supposed to be guaranteed that the font size in my page will basically be the same as the font size of the interface elements, and no unnecessary scrolling should appear, either.

As per above, is there a way to ensure `vw` / `vh` / `vmin` / `vmax` to never ever go below the absolute value of the above relative `1em`?  Perhaps something do with with [CSS4](http://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/) / [CSS3 media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) (`dpi`, `width`, `length` etc)?

Comment: Basically, I'm looking for some sort of a visual relationship between em, dpi, width/height and vw.  I'm pretty sure there's some concrete math to all of this, but too lazy to figure it out on my own.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, a `vw` unit is supposed to represent 1% (i.e. 1/100th) of the width of the viewport.  (Can anyone confirm if it's roughly the same for the paged media?)

As such, if the viewport width is `50em`, then `1vw` will equal `0.5em`, or, in other words, `1em` will equal `2vw`.

As such, it would indeed be a good idea to only ever use the `vw` unit within a media query; it seems like the easiest and most practical visual design and the math would be to target a minimum of `50em` width (and also height) as above, and then `2vw` (or, if we target minimum height with our media query, too, `2vmin`) would guarantee to mean at least `1em`, or, in other words, it would guarantee that the magnification will always be at least 100%.

For example, as for OpenBSD ports category listing, the following could be used to magnify the list of the categories (if the window itself is oversized and has sufficient height, too) without affecting the rest of the page nor diminishing the experience on the smaller-sized windows.  Here, we use `vmin` to combat against too much magnification in landscape view (which would result in up/down scrolling), but you have to be careful to also specify a `min-height` of at least `50em`, too (otherwise, we'll be getting below 100% magnification with `2vmin`, if the height were to fall below `50em`).

```
@media (min-width: 50em) and (min-height: 50em) {
  /* guarantees at least 1em in all viewports */
  ul {font-size: 2vmin; -webkit-columns: 4;}
}
```

(Note that the above appears to detach the `ul` elements from being zoomable by the user when the rules apply (at least when tested in my Google Chrome), so, overall, the question for best practice still stands.)

Or, for a small business-card-style front page, which only lists your name/address/contact details:

```
/* automatically magnify business-card-style page in large viewports */
/* please don't use this unless you yourself posses a large monitor! */
@media (min-width: 50em) and (min-height: 64em) {
  /* start with 100% at 50em, we'll have 150% magnification at 75em */
  html {font-size: 2vmin;}
}
@media (min-width: 75em) and (min-height: 96em) {
  /* start with 225% magnification at 75em (75 / 100 * 3 = 2.25) */
  html {font-size: 3vmin;}
}
```

As I was writing this, I also realised that in order to avoid so much magnification as to cause the introduction of the scrolling, it seems like we must absolutely specify both the `min-width` and `min-height` of something like `50em`, and then also use only the `vmin` as our unit.  Otherwise, a really widescreen window will be magnified way too much with mere `2vw`, such that excessive and unnecessary scrolling is very likely to get introduced.

Comment: I'm not too happy with this answer.  Basically, it seems like min-height in this context is absolute, yet font-size will be relative, so, the whole relationship will not be guaranteed on large monitors with weird aspect-ratios...